# Download csv file with date using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the [link](http://wesm.ph/chart/export/luzon_dmd_csv_export.php?date=20160115&hour=24) that I need to download.

My problem is the date. My sample code does not accept this kind of URL. Can you help me on this guys? Thanks!

```
import urllib2

url = "wesm.ph/chart/export/luzon_dmd_csv_export.php?date=201705&hour=24"

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
buffer = u.read(block_sz)
if not buffer:
    break

file_size_dl += len(buffer)
f.write(buffer)
status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. /    file_size)
status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
print status,

f.close()
```

Comment: About that sample code...could you show it, or at least relevant excerpts from it?

Comment: I've already edited my post. My sample code was posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes in the code sample above. 
Add "http://" to the url. 
querystring should be added in the following way:

```
url = "http://wesm.ph/chart/export/luzon_dmd_csv_export.php"
queryargs = { 'date':'201705', 'hour':'24' }
data = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
u = urllib.urlopen(url,data)
```

The code should end up as this:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "http://wesm.ph/chart/export/luzon_dmd_csv_export.php"
queryargs = { 'date':'201705', 'hour':'24' }
data = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
file_name = url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-1]+'.csv'
u = urllib.urlopen(url,data)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. /    file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,

f.close()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It works but the code is downloading php file not the csv file.

Comment: This is due to the file_name  being set as php. we need to edit that piece. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://wesm.ph/chart/export/luzon_dmd_csv_export.php?date=20160115&hour=24', stream=True)
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Just use `requests`

Comment: I got this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/StarComm/Desktop/PYTHON/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests"

Comment: I've already install easy_install via command prompt but it says error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified

Comment: I am using windows 7 64 bit

Comment: @LitongLambot  use pip

Comment: now it says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy_install-2.7 no matching distribution found for easy_install

Comment: any methods to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: @LitongLambot  yes, use python3 and never use python2.